# android: button pressed and to follow gesture

Tags: android, button, view, gesture

I am having an extended view.

Inside the extended view, there is a button. I would like to have a gesture listener such that when the button is touched and swiped to the right / left, the button will follow the finger to right / left.

What I have implemented is that in the main activity,

### main activity:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
   {
       int x = (int)event.getX();
       int y = (int)event.getY();

       if (y > viewHeight - 250)
       {
           game_collecting_ex_view.get_touched_x(x);   
       }
       switch (event.getAction()) 
       {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       }
   return false;
   }
```

### extended view:

```
   public void get_touched_x (int x)
   {       
        boy_x = x;
        image_boy.setX(boy_x); 
        image_boy.setY(viewHeight - BOY_HEIGHT);    
   }
```

### Question:

In this way, when I press any place other than the button, the button will follow the finger and move to left or right. Yet if pressing on the button, it will not move.

How could it be modified? Thanks!

Comment: how to use `public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) ` ?? I have googled and most are just using `onFling`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally have managed to implement `onTouch`'s `ACTION_MOVE` as the following to make the button as touch and drag:

```
  button_test= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_test);
  button_test.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
  {               
      private float x, y;    
      private int mx, my;             
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
      {    
          switch(event.getAction()) 
          {     
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:    
              x = event.getX();    
              y = event.getY();    
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:    
              mx = (int)(event.getRawX() - x);    
              my = (int)(event.getRawY() - 50 - y);    
              button_test.setX(mx);
              button_test.setY(my);

              break;    
          }    
          return true;    
      }});
```